# How do I combine multiple text filled rows into one in Python?

Tags: python

So I have like 20,000 rows in a single column in Excel that contains all text. I'm trying to combine all the rows into a single cell that I call 'message' so then I can do some stuff in TextBlob, like count the number of sentences, but I'm not having any success combining all the text rows into one.

input (cant seem to copy and paste but formatted as a single column)

```
MsgBody
sure can
race game 
like one of the biggest games
```

desired output:

```
sure can, race game, like one of the biggest games
```

actual output:

```
sure can
```

```
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd

input_csv = pd.read_csv(r'output.csv')
messages = input_csv['MsgBody']

allMessages = []

for message in messages:
    allMessages.append(message)
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you having empty string or what?

Comment: It's only grabbing one row. I just want to bring them all together but not having success. So Im not getting an error or anything, just not desired result

Comment: Could you share csv file too?

Comment: FWIW, this is simpler: `allMessages = list(messages)`

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including input, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: Do you want to do `'\n'.join(messages)` or something like that? What exactly do you mean by "combine all the rows into a single cell"?

Comment: @nagmat I tried copying and pasting part of the file but Overstack says I dont have enough credit to be able to post

Comment: @KenY-N i updated the formatting in my question, hopefully that explains better

Comment: Where's that output coming from? Your code doesn't print anything.

Comment: Just so you know, the message you get about copying/pasting and not having enough credit is [an April Fools joke](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406398/2605758), you can safely ignore it or click "Don't show again" on the popup.

Answer (score 2):

With the full spec now, it seems you just want:

```
', '.join(messages)
```

This will take the array and transform it into a single comma-separated string.

PS: The copy-paste credit posting thing is an [April Fool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406399/1270789) that seems rather counterproductive.